# Check if type is Eigen3 type

Tags: c++, templates, eigen3

## Eigen3 and built-in type inter-compatibility

Hello guys. I'm stuck with the problem of writing routines which can handle both Eigen3 types (Matrixes and Arrays) and built-in types. I can best explain this with an example: let's suppose I have a `Meter<Type>` template class which has the ability to collect statistics during runtime.

The Type class should support the following operators:

- `operator=(Scalar)`
- `operator=(Type)`
- `operator+(Type)`
- `operator-(Type)`
- `operator*(Type)`
- `operator/(Type)`
- `operator*(Scalar)`
- `operator/(Scalar)`

`Eigen3` types provides all of these operators with two exceptions: first, the `operator*(Type)` represents a dot-preduct if `Type` is some subclass of `Eigen::MatrixBase` and represents a coefficient-wise product if `Type` is some subclass of `Eigen::ArrayBase`. I can easily workaround this; second, neither one implements an `operator=(Scalar)` required for ensuring the correct initialization to zero.

I tried implementing the following functor classes to help me take care of the distinction but I can't get them to work:

some structs to handle the distrinction between built-in types and `Eigen3` types:

```
template < class _Type > struct is_scalar : true_type {
    using Scalar = _Type;
    using Type = _Type;

    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template < class _Matrix >
struct is_scalar<Eigen::MatrixBase<_Matrix>> : false_type {
    using Scalar = typename Matrix::Scalar;
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template < class _Array >
struct is_scalar<Eigen::ArrayBase<_Array>>  : false_type {
    using Scalar = typename Array::Scalar;
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};
```

the function implementation itself

```
template < class Scalar, bool is_scalar = Math::is_scalar<Scalar>::value > 
struct set_const_impl;

template < class Scalar >
struct set_const_impl< Scalar, true > {
    static const void run(Scalar &_x, Scalar _y) noexcept { _x = _y; }
};

template < class EigenType >
struct set_const_impl<EigenType, false> {
    template < class Scalar >
    static const void run(Eigen::EigenBase<EigenType> &_x, Scalar _y) noexcept {
        _x.derived().setConstant(_y);
    }
};

template < class Type, class Scalar > void set_const(Type &_x, Scalar _y) noexcept {
    set_const_impl<Type>::run(_x, _y);
}

template < class Type > void set_zero(Type &_x) noexcept {
    set_const_impl<Type>::run(_x, 0);
}
```

The specialized version `set_const_impl<EigenType>` never gets instantiated. For example, if I call

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> m1; 
set_zero(m1);
```

I get the compiler to complain at the `0` on the line

```
set_const_impl<Type>::run(_x, 0);
```

saying that `0` is not implicitly convertible to `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>`, which means it picked the `set_const_impl<Scalar, true>` version of the functor (where both arguments share a the common type `Scalar`). This also means that my `is_scalar` construction isn't working in this case, even if I've already used it and tested it on other classes without problems.

I need this behaviour in several other classes and I don't want to explicitly specialize each one of them! Anyone knows what should I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Jarod42

Thank you, your suggestion has brought some light but I found another option which I think will be pretty solid: I found an implementation of `is_scalar<Type>` in the namespace `std::__1`. Now my code reads

```
template < class Type, bool _is_scalar = std::__1::is_scalar<Type>::value > struct is_scalar;

template < class Type >
struct is_scalar<Type, true> : true_type {
    using Scalar = Type;
};

template < class Type >
struct is_scalar<Type, false> : false_type {
    using Scalar = typename Type::Scalar;
};
```

and I am correctly able to distinguish built-in and Eigen types! Thank you anyway!

Edit:

By looking at the source code of `std::__1::is_scalar` I also note that this solution might stand for any kind of container object as long as it provides a type `Scalar` which is

- an arithmetic type OR
- a member pointer OR
- a pointer OR
- a null pointer OR
- an enumeration constant

Am I correct?

Comment: I would very strongly advise against directly using anything from the std::__1 namespace. It is specific to libc++ and is not intended to be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your traits `is_scalar` which takes only base classes and not derived classes.

You may try something like:

```
namespace Helper
{
    template <typename T> std::false_type is_scalar(const Eigen::MatrixBase<T>*);
    template <typename T> std::false_type is_scalar(const Eigen::ArrayBase<T>*);
    std::true_type is_scalar(...);
}

template<typename T>
struct is_scalar : decltype(Helper::is_scalar(std::declval<T*>()))
{};
```

Answer (score 1):

I encounted the same problem, and tried to solve it with C++17. Here is my solution.

```
template<typename Derived>
constexpr bool is_eigen_type_f(const EigenBase<Derived> *) {
    return true;
}
constexpr bool is_eigen_type_f(const void *) {
    return false;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_eigen_type = is_eigen_type_f(reinterpret_cast<T *>(NULL));
```